# Constructing a graph and converting it to CSR representation

Tags: python, matrix, graph, compression, networkx

After constructing a graph using python networkx library, I want to obtain the CSR representation of the graph. Is there any existing method to do so?

Basically I want the index and the offset arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little hazy on what you want exactly, if you included your workings and a more concrete example it might help. However, I had a read through the documentation and it looks like there might be a few ways of doing what you would like: the [to_scipy_sparse_matrix](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix.html#networkx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix) looks like a likely choice.

Comment: I suggested the same thing, but it is not what he meant. He said that CSR representation is different from sparse matrix representation

Comment: @Abdallah_Sobehy If you read the documentation that method says it returns a scipy sparse matrix in CSR form as default, though. If Apurv could provide a concrete example of what he has, what output he desires and what he progres he has made so far along with some code examples, I can help more.